# Layout subviews not working properly

Tags: uiview, swift

I have troubles with a custom view that Im designing. 
Its essentially a table that display 12 labels, where the upper left label and the lower left label has to be width*5 of the other views. I have already added the views and adjusted the frame in layout subviews, but the labels does not appear in the view (already checked with the new views debugger of Xcode

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let width = self.frame.size.width
    let height = self.frame.size.height

    let normalWidth = width/10
    let normalHeight = height/2


    var currentOrigin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    let nameSize = CGSize(width: normalWidth * 5 - 3, height: normalHeight)

    labels[0][0].frame = CGRect(origin: currentOrigin, size: nameSize)

    currentOrigin.x += normalWidth

    for j in labels[0]{
        j.frame = CGRect(origin: currentOrigin, size: CGSize(width: normalWidth - 3, height: normalHeight))
        currentOrigin.x += normalWidth
    }

    currentOrigin.y = normalHeight
    currentOrigin.x = 0
    labels[1][0].frame = CGRect(origin: currentOrigin, size: nameSize)

    for j in labels[1]{
        j.frame = CGRect(origin: currentOrigin, size: CGSize(width: normalWidth - 3, height: normalHeight))
        currentOrigin.x += normalWidth
    }
}
```

And this is the constructor that Im using. According to the debugger the views are in the superview but they are not visible

```
 init(frame: CGRect) {
    labels = Array(count:2, repeatedValue:Array(count:6, repeatedValue: UILabel() ))
    super.init(frame: frame)

    for i in 0..labels.count{
        for j in 0..labels[i].count{
            labels[i][j] = UILabel()
            labels[i][j].font = currentFont
            labels[i][j].adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            labels[i][j].textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            labels[i][j].text = "HOLA MUNDO"
            addSubview(labels[i][j])
        }
    }

    for i in 0..labels.count{
        if let k = delegate?{
            labels[i][0].text = k.name(i+1)
        }
    }


    for i in 0..labels.count{
        for j in 1..labels[i].count{
            labels[i][j].text = "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone has some similar troubles here is the solution that I finally found

```
 labels = Array(count:2, repeatedValue:Array(count:6, repeatedValue: UILabel() ))
```

This line generates 2 arrays of UILabels, but all items of the arrays point to the same instance of UILabel. also:

```
  labels[0] === labels[1] //They will point to the same instance
```

The other mistake was iterating in

```
 for i in 0..labels.count{
    if let k = delegate?{
        labels[i][0].text = k.name(i+1)
    }
}
```

The correct thing  was to iterate from 1 to labels.count as the first label had to have a different size.

The correct form to instanciate the arrays is the following:

```
  for i in 0..2{
        labels.append([UILabel]())
        for j in 0..6{
            labels[i].append(UILabel())
            labels[i][j].font = currentFont
            labels[i][j].adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            labels[i][j].textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            labels[i][j].text = "HOLA MUNDO"
                addSubview(labels[i][j])

        }
```

Hope it help you to avoid this bug. It was really hard to find.